# Telerik RadGrid - Not giving new value in the UpdateCommand event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

The problem i am facing is in this line.

**decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Amt.Text);**

Amt.Text is not giving me the new entered value when i change it and try to save it. But it is giving me the old value. I don't know why ? Please suggest the fix.

I have a search button also in the webpage which is needed to rebind the Grid with the latest data. I think when i click the save link and gvLineItems_UpdateCommand is called , the rebinding is happening before that on the RADGRID (internally).

ASPX Code:-

```
<asp:content id="Content2" contentplaceholderid="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script language="javascript">
        function captureVal(sender, args){
            alert('hi');            
        }
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPartnerID" runat="server" Text="PartnerID" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="tbPartnerID" runat="server" MaxLength="35" Width="243px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Width="80px" Visible="true" Text="Search"   />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:right">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Visible="true" Text="Save"  />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left">
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Visible="true" Text="Cancel" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>
            Partner SSN/TIN:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="tbPartnerEIN" runat="server" MaxLength="9" TabIndex="5">
            </telerik:RadTextBox>&nbsp;
            <label id="Label1" runat="Server" style="color: Navy">* No Dashes</label>
        </td>
       <td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td style="text-align:left">
            Address Line 1:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="tbAddressLine1" runat="server" TabIndex="10" />&nbsp;
            <label id="label2" runat="server" style="color: navy">
                * No dashes</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Custodial EIN:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="tbCustodialEIN" runat="server" MaxLength="9" TabIndex="10">
            </telerik:RadTextBox>&nbsp;
            <label id="Label3" runat="Server" style="color: Navy">* No Dashes</label>
        </td>
         <td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td style="text-align:left">
            Address Line 2:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="tbAddressLine2" runat="server" TabIndex="10" />
            <label id="Label4" runat="Server" style="color: Navy">
                * No Dashes</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Format SSN/TIN:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cboFormatSSNTIN" Height="200px" runat="server" Width="246px"
                TabIndex="41">
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="" Value="" />
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="XXX-XX-XXXX" Value="0" />
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="XX-XXXXXXX" Value="1" />
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
        </td>
         <td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td style="text-align:left">
            City:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="tbCity" runat="server" MaxLength="22" Width="243px" TabIndex="45" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Partner Name 1:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="tbPartnerName1" runat="server" MaxLength="35" Width="243px"
                TabIndex="15" />
        </td>
         <td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td style="text-align:left">
            State:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlState" runat="server" AllowCustomText="true" Filter="Contains"
                Width="243px" TabIndex="35" Height="100" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Partner Name 2:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="tbPartnerName2" runat="server" MaxLength="35" Width="243px"
                TabIndex="20" />
        </td>
         <td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td style="text-align:left">
            Zip:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="tbZipcode" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="243px" TabIndex="55" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Entity Type:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="lbEntityType" Height="150px" runat="server" Width="246px"
                TabIndex="40" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Requiredfieldvalidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Select any one Entity type"
                ControlToValidate="lbEntityType" InitialValue="0" Display="None">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
         <td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td style="text-align:left">
            Foreign Address:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="tbForeignAddress" runat="server" Width="243px" TabIndex="35" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        </td>
         <td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td style="text-align:left">
            Domestic or Foreign:
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="lbCountry" runat="server" Width="246px" TabIndex="35" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbFinalAmend" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem>Final K-1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Amended K-1</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
             <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbGenLtd" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem>General partner or LLC member-manager</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Limited partner or other LLC member</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>

         <td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td>
            Nonrecourse
        </td>

        <td>
            $<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtNonrecourse" DataType="System.Double" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2"
                Width="200px" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbTax" Text="Tax basis" runat="server" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbGaap" Text="GAAP" runat="server" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSection" Text="Section 704(b) book" runat="server" />
        </td>
         <td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td>
            Qualified nonrecourse financing
        </td>

        <td>
            $<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtQualified" DataType="System.Double" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2"
                Width="200px" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbOther" Text="Other(explain)" runat="server" />
        </td>
         <td style="width:10px"></td>
        <td>
            Recourse
        </td>

        <td>
            $<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtRecourse" DataType="System.Double" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2"
                Width="200px" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <br />
            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt">(M) Did the partner contribute property
                with a built-in gain or loss?</span>
            <br />
            <hr size="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbContributedProperty" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <thead colspan="2">
                                <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt">(L) Partner's capital account analysis</span>
                                </thead>
                                <hr size="1" />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Beginning capital account
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    $<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtCapBeginning" DataType="System.Double" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2"
                                        Width="200px" runat="server">
                                    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Capital contributed during the year
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    $<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtCapContributed" DataType="System.Double" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2"
                                        Width="200px" runat="server">
                                    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Current year increase(decrease)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    $<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtIncrease" DataType="System.Double" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2"
                                        Width="200px" runat="server">
                                    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Withdrawals & distributions <span style="color: Red">(-)</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    $<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtWithdrawals" DataType="System.Double" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2"
                                        Width="200px" ForeColor="Red" runat="server">
                                    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Ending capital account
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    $<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtCapEnding" DataType="System.Double" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2"
                                        Width="200px" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <b>&nbsp;Beginning</b>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <b>Ending</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Profit
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtBeginningProfit" DataType="System.Double"
                            NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="6" Width="200px" runat="server" />%
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtEndProfit" DataType="System.Double" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="6"
                            Width="200px" runat="server" />%
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Loss
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtBeginningLoss" DataType="System.Double"
                            NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="6" Width="200px" runat="server" />%
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtEndLoss" DataType="System.Double" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="6"
                            Width="200px" runat="server" />%
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Capital
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtBeginningCap" DataType="System.Double"
                            NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="6" Width="200px" runat="server" />%
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtEndCap" DataType="System.Double" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="6"
                            Width="200px" runat="server" />%
                    </td>
                </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="gvLineItems" AllowMultiRowSelection="true" AllowMultiRowEdit="False" 
        AllowAutomaticUpdates="false" AllowAutomaticInserts="false" Width="100%" AllowAutomaticDeletes="False" GridLines="None" Pagesize="10" 
        AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PagerStyle-Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" OnNeedDataSource="gvLineItems_NeedDataSource">
            <MasterTableView InsertItemDisplay="Bottom" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowAutomaticUpdates="false" EditMode="InPlace" 
                DataKeyNames="SchK1ID,LineNumber,LineCode,Amount"
                AllowAutomaticDeletes="false" Width="100%"  AllowAutomaticInserts="false" CommandItemDisplay="None">
               <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="false" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn  HeaderText="Line Number" DataField="LineNumber" SortExpression="LineNumber" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn  HeaderText="Line Code" DataField="LineCode" SortExpression="LineCode" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn  HeaderText="Description" DataField="LineDescription" SortExpression="LineDescription" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataType="System.Decimal" HeaderText="Amount" DataField="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" UniqueName="Amount" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                        <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Amount", "{0:c}")%></ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>                                
                            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox  runat="server" id="tbAmount" width="75px" EmptyMessage="0" DataType="System.Decimal" Text='<%#Eval("Amount")%>' NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="3">                                    
                            </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>                                
                        </EditItemTemplate>                            
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="Save" ButtonType="LinkButton" EditText="Edit" InsertText="Insert" UpdateText="Save"/>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
            <ClientSettings>
                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"/>        

            </ClientSettings>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

C# Code Behind:

```
   public partial class EFileK1ImageEdit : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string m_EFSTaxPayerID;
        public int PartnerId {
            get {
                if (!string.Empty.Equals(tbPartnerID.Text.Trim())) {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(tbPartnerID.Text.Trim());
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
                this.LoadPartner();
                this.PopulateCapitalAccount();
            }
        }

        public void LoadPartner()
        {
            if (!(PartnerId == 0)) {
                Partner p = Partner.GetEfilePartnerByID(PartnerId, ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentYear(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentClient(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentUsername());
                if ((p != null)) {
                    PopulateInfo(p, ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentYear());
                }
            }
        }


        public void PopulateDropDowns()
        {
            this.lbEntityType.DataSource = IDMS.BusinessObjects.EntityCode.GetEntityType(ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentClient(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentUsername());
            this.lbEntityType.DataTextField = "Explanation";
            this.lbEntityType.DataValueField = "EntityCodeID";
            this.lbEntityType.DataBind();

            this.ddlState.DataSource = IDMS.BusinessObjects.SystemSettings.GetStateCodes(ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentClient(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentUsername());
            this.ddlState.DataTextField = "StateCode";
            this.ddlState.DataValueField = "StateCode";
            this.ddlState.DataBind();

            this.ddlState.Items.FindItemByText(".   ").Text = "FR";

            this.lbCountry.DataSource = IDMS.BusinessObjects.MailCode.GetAllMailCodes(ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentClient(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentUsername());
            this.lbCountry.DataTextField = "Explanation";
            this.lbCountry.DataValueField = "MailCodeID";
            this.lbCountry.DataBind();

        }


        private void SetStateControl(string value)
        {
            RadComboBoxItem item = this.ddlState.FindItemByValue(value);
            if (item == null) {
                this.ddlState.Text = value;
            } else {
                item.Selected = true;
            }

            if (value.Trim() == ".") {
                this.ddlState.Text = "";
            }
        }


        protected void PopulateInfo(Partner p, int taxYear)
        {
            PopulateDropDowns();
            this.tbPartnerID.Text = this.PartnerId.ToString();              
        }


        private void PopulateCapitalAccount()
        {
            IDMS.BusinessObjects.CapitalAccount ca = IDMS.BusinessObjects.CapitalAccount.GetEFileCapitalAccount(this.PartnerId, ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentYear(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentClient(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentUsername());

            //        SetManualAdjustmentMessage(ca)

            if (ca != null) {
                var _with1 = ca;
                this.rbFinalAmend.Items[0].Selected = _with1.FinalK1;
                this.rbFinalAmend.Items[1].Selected = _with1.AmendedK1;

                this.rbGenLtd.Items[0].Selected = _with1.GeneralPartner;
                this.rbGenLtd.Items[1].Selected = _with1.LimitedPartner;

                this.txtBeginningCap.Value = _with1.BeginningCapitalPercent * 100;
                this.txtBeginningLoss.Value = _with1.BeginningLossPercent * 100;
                this.txtBeginningProfit.Value = _with1.BeginningProfitPercent * 100;
                this.txtEndCap.Value = _with1.EndingCapitalPercent * 100;
                this.txtEndLoss.Value = _with1.EndingLossPercent * 100;
                this.txtEndProfit.Value = _with1.EndingProfitPercent * 100;

                this.txtNonrecourse.Value = _with1.LiabilityShareNonRecourse;
                this.txtQualified.Value = _with1.LiabilitySharedQualifiedNonRecourse;
                this.txtRecourse.Value = _with1.LiabilitySharedRecourse;

            } else {
                this.rbContributedProperty.Items[0].Selected = false;
                this.rbContributedProperty.Items[1].Selected = false;
            }

        }


        protected void gvLineItems_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs eventData)
        {
            //Validate Parameters
            if (eventData.Item is GridEditableItem && eventData.Item.IsInEditMode) {
                DataTable dt = IDMS.BusinessObjects.EfileMapping.GetEFileLineItemsByPartner(ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentClient(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentUsername(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentYear(), PartnerId);

                //Declare Variables
                GridEditableItem editableItem = eventData.Item as GridEditableItem;

                int LineNumber = Convert.ToInt32(editableItem.GetDataKeyValue("LineNumber"));
                string LineCode = Convert.ToString(editableItem.GetDataKeyValue("LineCode"));
                decimal oldAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Select(string.Format("LineNumber={0} and LineCode='{1}'", LineNumber, LineCode))[0]["Amount"]);
                RadNumericTextBox Amt = editableItem.FindControl("tbAmount") as RadNumericTextBox;
                decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Amt.Text);
                decimal diff = amount - oldAmount;
                txtIncrease.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtIncrease.Text) + diff).ToString();
                txtCapEnding.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtCapEnding.Text) + diff).ToString();

                saveCapitalAccount();
                IDMS.BusinessObjects.EfileMapping.UpdateEFileLineItemsByPartner(ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentClient(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentUsername(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentYear(), PartnerId, amount, LineNumber, LineCode);
            }
        }

        protected void gvLineItems_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            gvLineItems.DataSource = IDMS.BusinessObjects.EfileMapping.GetEFileLineItemsByPartner(ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentClient(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentUsername(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentYear(), PartnerId);
        }

        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.LoadPartner();
            this.PopulateCapitalAccount();
            gvLineItems.Rebind();
        }


        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            IDMS.BusinessObjects.Partner p = new IDMS.BusinessObjects.Partner();

            var _with2 = p;
            _with2.PartnerID = int.Parse(tbPartnerID.Text);
            _with2.EFSNameLine1 = tbPartnerName1.Text;    
        UpdateEFileDetailPartnerGridByYear(ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentClient(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentYear(), this.PartnerId);
        }


        public void saveCapitalAccount()
        {
            IDMS.BusinessObjects.CapitalAccount ca = new IDMS.BusinessObjects.CapitalAccount();
            var _with3 = ca;
            _with3.PartnerID = this.PartnerId;
            _with3.CalendarYear = ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentYear();

            _with3.FinalK1 = this.rbFinalAmend.Items[0].Selected;
            _with3.AmendedK1 = this.rbFinalAmend.Items[1].Selected;

            _with3.GeneralPartner = this.rbGenLtd.Items[0].Selected;
            _with3.LimitedPartner = this.rbGenLtd.Items[1].Selected;


            _with3.BeginningCapitalPercent = this.txtBeginningCap.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0) / 100;
            _with3.BeginningLossPercent = this.txtBeginningLoss.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0) / 100;
            _with3.BeginningProfitPercent = this.txtBeginningProfit.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0) / 100;
            _with3.EndingCapitalPercent = this.txtEndCap.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0) / 100;
            _with3.EndingLossPercent = this.txtEndLoss.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0) / 100;
            _with3.EndingProfitPercent = this.txtEndProfit.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0) / 100;

            _with3.LiabilityShareNonRecourse = this.txtNonrecourse.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0);
            _with3.LiabilitySharedQualifiedNonRecourse = this.txtQualified.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0);
            _with3.LiabilitySharedRecourse = this.txtRecourse.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0);

            _with3.AccountAnalysisBeginningCapital = this.txtCapBeginning.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0);
            _with3.AccountAnalysisContributions = this.txtCapContributed.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0);
            _with3.AccountAnalysisIncreaseDecrease = this.txtIncrease.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0);
            _with3.AccountAnalysisWithdrawalsDistributions = this.txtWithdrawals.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0);
            _with3.AccountAnalysisEndingCapital = _with3.AccountAnalysisBeginningCapital + _with3.AccountAnalysisContributions + _with3.AccountAnalysisIncreaseDecrease - _with3.AccountAnalysisWithdrawalsDistributions;

            _with3.AccountAnalysisGAAP = this.cbGaap.Checked;
            _with3.AccountAnalysisOther = this.cbOther.Checked;
            _with3.AccountAnalysisSection704b = this.cbSection.Checked;
            _with3.AccountAnalysisTaxBasis = this.cbTax.Checked;

            _with3.ContributePropertyYes = this.rbContributedProperty.Items[0].Selected;
            _with3.ContributePropertyNo = this.rbContributedProperty.Items[1].Selected;

            _with3.SaveEfile(ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentClient(), ProfileExtensions.GetCurrentUsername());
        }
        public EFileK1ImageEdit()
        {
            Load += Page_Load;
            Init +=EFileK1ImageEdit_Init;
        }

        private void EFileK1ImageEdit_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            btnSave.Click+=btnSave_Click;
            btnCancel.Click +=btnCancel_Click;
            btnSearch.Click+=btnSearch_Click;
            gvLineItems.NeedDataSource +=gvLineItems_NeedDataSource;
            gvLineItems.UpdateCommand +=gvLineItems_UpdateCommand;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked if in the db the new value is there?

Comment: During the debugging, i found even the dbValue property has a older value.

Comment: Please read again my comment. Which value you have in the db? Old or new?

Comment: It is having the old value. It is having the DB call afterwards.

Comment: Then you are not saving the new value correctly. So your problem is somewhere else not in the line you mentioned in your question.

Comment: When i hit "Save" link, it saves the older value only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73346/discussion-between-felicem-and-karan).

Comment: Your grid is rebind before you access updated value from textbox so could you please provide full C# code so we will try to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi @Jayesh - I have updated the above code sample. Please advise.

Comment: @Karan, To identify the issue we required full page code.

Comment: I added the complete ASPX code.

Comment: @Jayesh, please take a look. I added the complete code.